# Efficient way of saving multiple images of different size as hdf5 (h5py)

Tags: h5py, image-compression

I have millions of images that are quite small in size, each of them is a different size but are generally quite small (~100x100).
What is the best way to save them into a single hdf5 file? The main reason I want to save them as a single file is because I don't want to run out of inodes.
Currently, the saved file is huge (x10 bigger than when saved as pngs). I tried using h5py's compression option as shown below. However this results in a bigger file than without compression.

```
hf_img = h5py.File("imgs.hdf5", "w")
for img in imgs:
    hf_img.create_dataset(prefix, data=img, compression="gzip", compression_opts=9)
hf_img.close()
```

I heard the larger compressed file has to do with chunking but I don't understand how to set up chunking efficiently.

Comment: I think this [link](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/745) might be useful to you.